# Image not found React Native (Expo)

Tags: react-native, image, expo, blob, avatar

Hello fellow programmers,

I am trying to show an image using the `UserAvatar` component in React-Native (Expo) but I am facing a problem where the link I am getting from the API is not working `404 Not Found`, what is the best possible way to avoid this problem. I tried to create a blob using the URL of the image but it was not successful

This is the error message i am getting in the app

```
Online fetched source is not a supported image at node_modules/react-native-user-avatar/src/helpers.js:41:6 in fetchImage
```

Here is one of the solutions i have tried:

```
urlToBlob = (url) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onerror = reject;
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    resolve(xhr.response);
  }
};
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.responseType = 'blob'; // convert type
xhr.send();
})this.urlToBlob(data)
        .then((blob) => {
          console.log(blob);
        });
```

Comment: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-user-avatar` expect local or remote image. Why you're fetching BLOD image data?

Comment: the problem i have is that the remote links i have for the image sometimes it does not work, so i am stuck with a link that has no image and gets a 404, so the onl possibility i have is to ping on that remote url to see if the response status is 200 or 400 and based on that determine what image is to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach that i took to solve this problem is very simple.

```
      axios
        .get(image_url)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.status === 200) {
            setImageStatus(200);
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setImageStatus(err.response.status);
        });
    }
```

When the response status is 200 then the image exists if not fallback to the default image.